# Typescript and React: What is the proper type for an event handler that uses destructuring?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling, destructuring

I'm having problems with the strictness of Typescript when using event handlers with React.  Specifically, I am unable to use object destructuring with my `handleClick()` function that goes on the `onClick={handleClick}` attribute.

This is the unclean version, and it is the only one typescript acceps without complaining:

```
const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    const target: Element = event.target as Element
    // ...other code goes here
}
```

This is the clean version, and typescript throws errors:

```
const handleClick = ({ target }: { target: Element }) => {
    // ...other code goes here
}
```

The second block of code (the unclean version) causes Typescript to throw an error.  When I hover over the onClick={handleClick} attribute, this frutratingly cryptic error is displayed:

> Type '({ target }: { target: Element; }) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.
> Types of parameters '__0' and 'event' are incompatible.
> Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type '{ target: Element; }'.
> Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
> Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 120 more.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(1457, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>'

Does anybody have a solution to this?  I am stumped.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use the same type `React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>` for the destructured parameter. This will infer the correct type for `target`. You'll probably want to use `currentTarget` though, which is the element the handler was attached to, rather than `target`, which is the element the event occurred on. For a button they will be the same, but TypeScript can only infer the actual element type for `currentTarget`.

```
import * as React from "react";

const handleClick = ({ target, currentTarget }: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    // target: EventTarget
    // currentTarget: EventTarget & HTMLButtonElement

    // ...other code goes here
}

const elt = <button onClick={handleClick} />
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwCwAUI7hAHarwAWyrAJgDZYAwv2C4A1nAC8cABQBvODGRQA5lhgAaOLgCuUSqxgAVFevgBfAFyYqMAHQBZCLtRYAogDcsRgDwAJY0cAGQAhXRgYNndBEB8YAD4ASmkEuHlGOCy4AHocpTMNGy940zUNTOy8nX1DE0KYYu8jMvM4ADI4QJDwyOjY+MZKrOr7MYgYTiwoHQheLDhVCCx0KcpGCyGGFnZ4LH54GV8AIwio1jg2ETFxKXluPkFriQtchMYgA)

Comment: Amazing.  Works like a charm.  Thanks for the pointer about "target" vs. "currentTarget" as well!